# JARS not found by MANIFEST.FM

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jde

I'm currently developing an eclipse plug-in, so I just started using JDE.
I referrenced all the JARs needed in my project, yet I keep having errors in my MANIFEST.MF :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Module-builder
Bundle-SymbolicName: module-builder;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: module_builder.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

the errors being

```
org.eclipse.ui cannot be resolved
org.eclipse.core.runtime cannot be resolved
```

Where could those errors be coming from ?

EDIT :
As asked, the .project content :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
        <name>module-builder</name>
        <comment></comment>
        <projects>
        </projects>
        <buildSpec>
                <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
                        <arguments>
                        </arguments>
                </buildCommand>
                <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.eclipse.pde.ManifestBuilder</name>
                        <arguments>
                        </arguments>
                </buildCommand>
                <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.eclipse.pde.SchemaBuilder</name>
                        <arguments>
                        </arguments>
                </buildCommand>
        </buildSpec>
        <natures>
                <nature>org.eclipse.pde.PluginNature</nature>
                <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: When are you getting these errors?

Comment: They just are in the MANIFEST.FM in Eclipse.

Comment: Are you sure this is a Eclipse plugin project? Show us the contents of the `.project` file.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit to show you the .project content.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. What do you have for the Target Platform (in the Preferences, 'Plug-in Development > Target Platform')?

Comment: I seem to have a lot of files missing in the eclipse-mars/dropins and eclipse-mars/plugin, the problem certainly comes from there, thanks !